# Camel Aggregator : Stop route on first failure and retain all messages in the repository

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have setup my aggregator as follows.

```
    LevelDBAggregationRepository repository = new LevelDBAggregationRepository(REPO_NAME, repoLocation+"/"+REPO_NAME+".dat"); 
    repository.setUseRecovery(true); 
    repository.setMaximumRedeliveries(3); 
    repository.setRecoveryInterval(3000); 
    repository.setDeadLetterUri("mock:dead"); 

    from(UPDATE_ENDPOINT) 
            .aggregate(header("fileId"), new ESSessionAggregationStrategy()) // aggregates into an arraylist 
            .aggregationRepository(repository) 
            .completionPredicate(constant(false)) 
            .to("es://bulk") // my elasticsearch component
```

I am flushing all the aggregates by sending a message with the header Exchange.AGGREGATION_COMPLETE_ALL_GROUPS=true.

If elasticsearch component is not available, I would like to stop the route with all messages in the repository. Basically I do not want any messages to be moved to the DeadLetter queue

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [route policy](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html) to control route status programmatically...

also see [this page](http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html) about how to stop a route from a route...